# How exactly are you supposed to loose belly-fat?

Tags: exercise, weight-loss

Im really at a loss to what I can further do to loose weight. The bottom part of my body is ripped. I really like the toned look of my legs, but this darn belly fat does not seem to want to go anywhere. I went from 125kg to 107kg last time I was weighed but still the man boobs and the kangaroo pouch remains.

My body type is stout and long. I'm 6,2 about 1.84 meters tall and thick set. I don't think I should ever weigh less than 95kgs

I really don't know how much more exercise I can do. I have been doing 70 - 80 km of walking per month for basically 2 years straight. I also cannot really think that the diet is the problem. I'm lactose intolerant so I went completely cold-turkey on the dairy.

My diet is 80 percent vegan, with maybe 4 - 6 times a month I will have some chicken or a piece of the swine, but that is the exception not the rule. I also don't drink sugar in my coffee or tea. I don't drink any soda-pop. I drink the occasional energy drink, but if the labels are to believed those drinks have 300 of your daily 8200 kilojoules in them.

I eat a lot of vegetables, I like my pumpkin and sweet potato. I eat a lot of legumes as well, beans and lentils are also a good part of my diet. I also don't eat a lot of bread or rice.

I'm beginning to think my weight issue are insurmountable. Every now and then I get so fatigued from my exercise that I lay comatose in my bed for whole weekends.

I really need some advice. A flat stomach is something I have never had and also something I have craved my whole life.

Comment: You're supposed to lose belly fat by losing body fat, there's no spot reduction. But there's not a lot of details to give you a proper answer: you weight 107kg, but at what _body fat percentage_? You eat, but how much protein / carbs / fat per day? How many calories? At 1.84m / 107kg I'd guess you still have quite some fat to lose if you have man boobs.

Comment: Walking is great but I think you should also do strength training. I had a bit too much belly 2 or 3 years ago and got rid of it by weight training with almost no changes to diet.